# Remove NTFS permissions of a user in all sub-directories

Tags: powershell, acl

I am writing a PowerShell script which would delete a specific user from all sub-directories.

Below script only removes the permission from the folder but I want to remove permission from all sub-folders as well.

```
$acl = get-acl c:\temp
$accessrule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ("domain\user","Read",,,"Allow")
$acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule)
Set-Acl -Path "c:\temp" -AclObject $acl
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting the acl of the root folder. `Set-Acl` by itself does not allow you to propagate to subfolders.

Note that that might not be what you want anyway. You want to remove a rule from all folders instead of replacing the acls on all subfolders with the acl of your root folder.

Safer would be to get the acl of each subfolder, remove the rule and set the acl of each subfolder.

`icacls`<sub>cudo's to Ansgar</sub> might be better for this task. A Powershell way might be as follows

```
$accessrule = New-Object system.security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("domain\user","Read",,,"Allow")
$root = 'c:\temp'
@(Get-Item $root) + @(Get-ChildItem $root -Recurse -Directory) | Foreach-Object {    
    $acl = Get-Acl $_.FullName
    $acl.RemoveAccessRuleAll($accessrule)
    Set-Acl $_.FullName -AclObject $acl -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: `cacls` should be avoided, as it doesn't handle inheritance properly. The most convenient way of dealing with permissions is probably `icacls`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Path = "c:\temp\"
$User = "admin"
$Account = new-object system.security.principal.ntaccount($User)

$ACL = Get-Acl -path $Path    
$ACL.PurgeAccessRules($Account)
$ACL  | Set-Acl -path $Path -Verbose

gci -Recurse -Path $Path -Directory | %{
    $ACL = Get-Acl -path $_.FullName    
    $ACL.PurgeAccessRules($Account)
    $ACL  | Set-Acl -path $_.FullName -Verbose
}
```

Comment: this works but fails when user account is not present in c:\temp and present in c:\temp\testing folder. So it does not remove the entry from c:\temp\testing

Comment: I'm sorry, this is my mistake, here is the fix! @Nishad Vartak

`$Path = "c:\temp\"
$User = "admin"
$Account = new-object system.security.principal.ntaccount($User)

gci -Recurse -Path $Path -Directory | %{
    $ACL = Get-Acl -path $_.FullName    
    $ACL.PurgeAccessRules($Account)
    $ACL | Set-Acl -path $_.FullName -Verbose
}
`

Comment: I don't see any changes in the fix.

Comment: Sorry. that's it.

Comment: `$Path = "c:\temp\"
 $User = "admin"
 $Account = new-object system.security.principal.ntaccount($User)

$ACL = Get-Acl -path $Path    
$ACL.PurgeAccessRules($Account)
$ACL  | Set-Acl -path $Path -Verbose

gci -Recurse -Path $Path -Directory | %{
    $ACL = Get-Acl -path $_.FullName    
    $ACL.PurgeAccessRules($Account)
    $ACL  | Set-Acl -path $_.FullName -Verbose
}`